# How can I merge two JSON files and then retrieve it?

Tags: javascript, json

I created a JSON file in order to access the data into one of my FramerJS prototypes. I know how to create basic JSON, but unfortunately I am struggling creating more complex ones.

The example below gives a hint of what I am trying to do. Is that correct?

```
{
    "bus":[{
            "id":1,
            "posX":1080,
            "posY":1575,
        },{
            "id":2,
            "posX":1080,
            "posY":1575,
        }],

    "trains":[{
            "id":1,
            "posX":1080,
            "posY":1575,
        }, {
            "id":2,
            "posX":1080,
            "posY":1575
        }
    ]
}
```

Second, how can I access its values? Is the following code below correct?

```
y: bus.posY
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `bus` is an array so either `bus[0].posY`or `bus[1].posY` depending on the object.

Comment: where are the parts to merge?, access is `object.bus[some index].posY`

Comment: y: bus.posY, why did you choose y: here? What do you want to do with the value you're getting from your data?

Comment: Does all your JSON files follows the same structure of the example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed that your object is:

```
var json = {
    "bus":[{
            "id":1,
            "posX":1080,
            "posY":1575,
        },{
            "id":2,
            "posX":1080,
            "posY":1575,
        }],

    "trains":[{
            "id":1,
            "posX":1080,
            "posY":1575,
        }, {
            "id":2,
            "posX":1080,
            "posY":1575
        }
    ]
};
```

Then, your bus is an array so you'll have to access it like explained below:

```
json.bus[0]["posY"] //will be 1575 

json.bus[0].posY //will be 1575
```

Or you can iterate (for) and get to your specific index.

```
json.bus[i]["posY"]

json.bus[i].posY
```

Answer (score 1):

> Second how can I access its value? Is the following code below
>   correct?

`bus` is an array, so you will have to

- Either iterate it to get the specific value

  `obj.bus[i].posX;` //i is the counter variable in the loop

this could be a for loop

```
 for ( var i = 0; i < obj.bus.length; i++)
 {
   console.log( obj.bus[i].posX );
 }
```

- choose the specific index value

  `obj.bus[0].posX;` //0 is the index of the object inside `bus`